# How can I proxy requests to an External Port in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have a web service running on a port on my local network exposed at port 6003. I also have a Kubernetes Cluster running on a different machine on the same network that uses and Nginx Ingress to proxy to all the services in the cluster. How can I set up an ingress to proxy to the machine? I had a set up that worked. But now, I am either getting DNS errors on the nginx pod or the response times out in the browser and nothing happens.

Here is the manifest I have been using.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 192.xxx.xx.x
ports:
  - name: myservice
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6003
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: myservice-ip
subsets:
  - addresses:
      # list all external ips for this service
      - ip: 192.xxx.xx.x
    ports:
      - name: myservice
        port: 6003
        protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service.example.com
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: service.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: myservice-service
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
  tls:
    - secretName: secret-prod-tls
      hosts:
        - service.example.com
```

**Edit for more information:**
This manifest does work. What I realized is that you **must** specify https even though the ingress has a tls block. This still is showing Lua DNS errors in the Nginx-ingress pod though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **MUST** specify `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"` in your ingress resource if upstream listening for HTTPS requests. So, this is related to backend, not ingress itself. 
**TLS** configuration is for Ingress (frontend), and not for backend application.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ExternalName here. Usual headless service will do the job:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-ip
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
  clusterIP: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-ip
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 172.17.0.5
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
```

Comment: It looks like that my current configuration does work as is. But if you try to hit it without explicitly typing https it will not reroute despite the tls block. I am still getting lua dns errors on the nginx-ingress pod as well, even with your changes. So, I will have to do more digging.

Comment: Headless service type is not `ClusterIP`, it should be `None`.

Comment: @coolinuxoid actually no, please read https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services

Comment: Yes, I checked and it is written "Sometimes you don’t need or want load-balancing and a single service IP. In this case, you can create “headless” services by specifying "None" for the cluster IP (.spec.clusterIP)."

Comment: that's exactly what is written in my manifest: "spec.clusterIP: None". Not "spec.type: None", you see? There is no such type of Service as "None". Please read carefully.